# Get all none contact from a user sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I hope you are well :).

I'm a little bit stuck with a problem in sql that I can't solve. I would like to get all the people who are not yet friends with a user without tuple.

That is to say that in my column user_id or contact_user_id, it would be necessary that if: user_id = 1 and contact_user_id = 2 (they are friends) that it does not show for the user 2 that it is not friends with user 1.

It should display for user 2 that he is missing user 3,4 and not 1 nor himself

I have for the moment a request of the kind but it does not display the good expected result.

Thanks a lot to the person who will take the time to answer

Their is the desired result without the first line (cause their are already friend) :

[image: Result desired]

I got for the moment this sql statement :

```
select us.user_id, us.login 
from user us where u.user_id!=2 
and not exists (select 1 from contact ctc 
where ctc.contact_user_id = us.user_id 
and ctc.user_id = 2);
```

EDIT : I maybe founded the sql request

```
select u.*
from user u
where not exists (select 1
                  from contact c
                  where (c.user_id = u.user_id and c.contact_user_id = 2) or (c.contact_user_id= u.user_id and c.user_id=2)
                 );
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results as text rather than as an unreadable image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want records where there is no reciprocal relationship (as your description implies), you can use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from contact c
where not exists (select 1
                  from contact c2
                  where c2.contact_user_id = c.user_id and
                        c.user_id = c.contact_user_id
                 );
```

If you want additional information from another table, just join in the outer query:

```
select c.*
from contact c join
     user u
     on c.user_id = u.user_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from contact c2
                  where c2.contact_user_id = c.user_id and
                        c.user_id = c.contact_user_id
                 );
```

Comment: Yeah the only problem, is that I already used a not exist. I want to get all the user from user table with no reciprocal relationship. But this sql statement is not what I searched (it only show none reciprocal from contact table

Comment: @Forcela8 . . . just use a join in the outer query.